# Sum with WHERE and GROUP BY CLAUSE

Tags: php, mysql

Good day. I am really in big trouble as I can't figure what is wrong with my statement. It is as follows:

```
$sumitem = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AS TOTAL FROM sum_query WHERE MAIN_ID = 1 GROUP BY ITEM_ID");
$sum = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sumitem);
```

I am trying to print $sum['TOTAL'] but what it shows the first column only. Below is my sample table:

```
MAIN_ID | ITEM_ID | AMOUNT |  DESC  | OTHER_DETAILS 
   1    |     1   |  500   | Item 1 |  a 
   1    |     2   |  5000  | Item 2 |  a 
   1    |     2   |  5000  | Item 2 |  b
```

My desired result should be 5500 but it only returns 500.
Thank you very much.

Comment: I can't replicate this finding. I get 500 and 6000

Comment: Don't you need to include `item_id` in the `select` clause?

Comment: simply use SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AS TOTAL FROM sum_query MAIN_ID = 1

Comment: Please check my last edit. Thank you guys

Comment: use GROUP BY OTHER_DETAILS

Comment: I don't understand how you expect to get that result. I'd expect 500 and 10000

Answer (score 1):

If you want ans as 6500 then remove `group by` clause

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AS TOTAL FROM sum_query WHERE MAIN_ID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(g.AMOUNT)  AS TOTAL 
    FROM sum_query g
   WHERE g.MAIN_ID = 1 
GROUP BY g.ITEM_ID
```

This query is working plase try out this

Comment: I had a mistake with the last portion of my question. Please check it out. I just edited it a few minutes earlier.

Comment: what is the result of var_dump($sum). plz comment your result

Comment: array(1) { ["TOTAL"]=> string(4) "500" }

Answer (score 0):

You are having 2 records for Item 2. and i don't know why you are keeping 'a and b' in OTHER_DETAILS.

Your requirement is not clear

If you want to take only the records matching with OTHER_DETAILS 'a',then use the following query

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AS TOTAL FROM sum_query WHERE MAIN_ID = 1 and OTHER_DETAILS = 'a'
```